# Lack of knowledge to correctly compose a query in MySql

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have an error in a SQL query and I can't figure out where the error is. Lack of knowledge.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT ptc.category_id, cd.name, c.oct_image FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category ptc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (cd.category_id = ptc.category_id)
 LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c ON (c.category_id = ptc.category_id) WHERE ptc.product_id IN (" . $product_ids . ") AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')."'  GROUP BY ptc.category_id");
```

I am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cd ON (cd.category_id = ptc.category_id) LEFT JOIN oc_category c ON (c.cate' at line 1
> Error No: 1064
> SELECT ptc.category_id, cd.name, c.oct_image FROM oc_product_to_category ptcoc_category_description cd ON (cd.category_id = ptc.category_id) LEFT JOIN oc_category c ON (c.category_id = ptc.category_id) WHERE ptc.product_id IN () AND cd.language_id = '1' GROUP BY ptc.category_id

Comment: try: `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT ptc.category_id, cd.name, c.oct_image FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category ptc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (cd.category_id = ptc.category_id)

LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c ON (c.category_id = ptc.category_id) AND ptc.product_id IN ('" . $product_ids . "') WHERE cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')."'  GROUP BY ptc.category_id");
`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't see the missing brackets...